# Adobe Animate simple tween whale flapping tail

Tags: vector, animation, adobe-animate

I need to tween animate a vector whale that simply waves it's tail up and down. I have created three graphics.
1. Whale tail straight
2. Whale tail up
3. Whale tail down

I attempted to use the shape tween but it was creating some unexpected crazy results. I tried reading up, searching etc but a lot of the search results are confused with After Effects. Is this possible to tween (somewhat) complex illustrated shapes in Adobe Animate?

The keyframe sequence I would like is:
1. Whale tail straight
2. Whale tail up
3. Whale tail straight
4. Whale tail down

Loop

[image]

Graphic here:
[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p91fu9d7lx3cdtp/whale-flaps-tail.ai?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Divide the body of the whale into 3 parts (or more) and use "Bone Tool" to animate. See the tutorials:

1) https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/how-to/bone-tool-animation.html

2) https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/how-to/layer-parenting.html

Thanks
;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

I ended up using the Puppet/Asset Warp tool. Will check out the links you posted.

You might like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OFtpPD8TYU ?

[image: Puppet/Asset Warp tool]
[image: Puppet warp Adobe Animate CC]

Shame I can't upload the file.mov here to show the results.